# Transformar um array de objetos em outro array de objetos com campos diferentes

Tags: javascript

Preciso transformar este *array* de objetos:

```js
const produto = [
  {
    produto: "Teclado",
    price: 12,
  },
  {
    produto: "mouse",
    price: 23,
  },
];
```

Especificamente, transformar em:

```js
const produtoTransform = [
  {
    descricao: "Teclado",
    valor: 12,
  },
  {
    descricao: "mouse",
    valor: 23,
  },
];
```

Esse ultimo valor é para poder passar para uma API. Tentei instanciar um objeto com `new Object`.

Comment: Recomendo aprender o básico do JavaScript, principalmente de arrays, recomendo aprender pela documentação da MDN, sugestões: [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) e [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 3):

Basta você utilizar a função `map` da sua lista, que, por definição, tem o objetivo de converter cada item da lista em outro:

```js
const produtoTransform = produto.map(item => ({
    'descrição': item.produto, 
    'valor': item.price
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

O laço de iteração [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) percorre objetos iterativos chamando uma bloco de código contendo instruções a serem executadas para o valor de cada objeto distinto.

```js
const produto = [{
  produto: 'Teclado',
  price: 12

}, {
  produto: 'mouse',
  price: 23

}];

let resultado = [];

for (let e of produto) {
  resultado.push({
    descrição: e.produto,
    valor: e.price
  });
}

console.log(resultado);

console.log(resultado[0].descrição);
```